# Foreign Attribute not reflecting in Database using One to One relationship using XML Mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

While learning Hibernate I have to create `One to One` relationship between two entities, mapping done using `*.hbm.xml`. But the created table doesn't shows the containing Entity.(Eg. In Employee it doesn't shows attribute address).

Code is below:

**Employee.java**

```
package com.sopra.hibernate121hbm;



public class Employee {


    private long empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastname;

    private Address address;

    public long getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(long empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}
```

**Address.java**

```
package com.sopra.hibernate121hbm;


public class Address {

    private long addressId;

    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;



    public long getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }
    public void setAddressId(long addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name ="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource= "Address.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource= "Employee.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25-Jan-2018 12:51:40 by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sopra.hibernate121hbm.Employee" table="EMP_ONE">
        <id name="empId" type="long">
            <column name="EMPID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String" >
            <column name="FIRSTNAME" length = "25"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastname" type="java.lang.String" >
            <column name="LASTNAME" length = "25" />
        </property>

        <one-to-one name="address" class="com.sopra.hibernate121hbm.Address" cascade="save-update" fetch="join">

        </one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Address.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 25-Jan-2018 12:46:58 by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sopra.hibernate121hbm.Address" table="ADDRESS">
        <id name="addressId" type="long">
            <column name="ADDRESSID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="street" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STREET" />
        </property>
        <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CITY" />
        </property>
        <property name="state" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STATE" />
        </property>


    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ManageEmployeeDB.java**

```
    package com.sopra.hibernate121hbm;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageEmployeeDB {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();

        Employee emp =  new Employee();
        Address address = new Address();

        address.setStreet("Crossing GH7");
        address.setCity("Ghaziabad");
        address.setState("Uttar Pradesh");

        emp.setFirstName("Salim");
        emp.setLastname("Shamim");

        emp.setAddress(address);

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(emp);
        session.persist(address);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }
}
```

I have tried adding `cascade = save-update`, but it was of no use.
Please help, I am stuck, can't figure out what's wrong.

PS: Mention any addition detail required in comments.

Comment: It could be because you have not mentioned joincolumn. Can you try that?

Comment: @GarimaGupta could you mention any reference on how to do that, because I can only find annotations for join column, and I need it using xml

Comment: You can try:
  <one-to-one name="address" class="com.sopra.hibernate121hbm.Address" cascade="save-update" fetch="join">
                           <join-column name="ADDRESSID"/>
</one-to-one>

Comment: Shows "The content of element type "one-to-one" must match "(meta*,formula*)"